# Trying to extract a patch given 8 points from NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array which looks like this

```
boxes = [268,885,426,865,406,707,248,727]
```

It's a collection of `(x,y)` points. If I plot this using this function:

```
def draw_boxes_on_image_mod(image, boxes):

  image_copy = image.copy()
  image_copy = np.array(image_copy)
  cv2.line(image_copy, (boxes[0],boxes[1]),(boxes[2],boxes[3]),(0,255,255),2)
  cv2.line(image_copy, (boxes[4], boxes[5]),(boxes[6],boxes[7]),(0,255,255),2)
  cv2.line(image_copy, (boxes[0],boxes[1]),(boxes[6],boxes[7]),(0,255,255),2)
  cv2.line(image_copy, (boxes[4], boxes[5]),(boxes[2],boxes[3]),(0,255,255),2)

  scipy. misc.imsave('/home/ryan/TEST.png', image_copy)
  return image_copy
```

I get an image with a rectangle drawn on the part of the image I'm interested in, But what I want is to extract that portion and convert it into an image.

I was thinking of using NumPy indexing to achieve this but

```
image = image[268:426]
```

I am finding it difficult to understand how to index the (x,y) values together.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you just call A[1:3] all you are asking for are the rows 1 and 2, the rows including  1 and stopping before 3, so you must take into account columns as well to get the exact subsection you need.

You can do this in numpy by stating the range of the rows and columns, the subsection of the array you want will start at a row and end at row + m as well as starting at a column and ending at column + n

For example take

```
 A = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

We want just the values in the middle set to 1, so we select them with

```
       Asub = A[1:3,1:3]
```

To get

```
               [[1 1]
                [1 1]]
```